# Real analysis Topology of open and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Since a A is a closed set if it contains all of its Cluster points, and also any closed set contains all of its Boundary points, What is the relationship between a boundary point and a cluster point? Is the intersection of the two sets always nonempty?

Is A' ∩ BdA ≠ ∅ ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would think that where ever you saw that definition of "closed set" you would also see definitions of "cluster point" and "boundary point"!  If I remember correctly a point, p, is a "cluster point" of a set, A, if and only if any neighborhood of p contains at least one point of the set (other than p itself if p happens to be in the set).  A point, p, is a "boundary point" of a set, A, if and only if every neighborhood of p contains at least one point of the set, A, and at least one point not in A.

For example, the disk, $\{(x,y)| x^2+ y^2\le 1\}$, has every point in it as a "cluster point" but the boundary points are only the points on the circle, $\{(x,y)|x^2+ y^2= 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that “cluster point” means the same as limit (or accumulation point): a point $x$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ different from $x$.

Let $A$ be a closed subset of the topological space $X$.

Can the boundary be empty? Yes, if and only if $A$ is also open. Indeed, if $A$ is open, it is a neighborhood of any of its points that doesn't intersect the complement of $A$. So no point of $A$ can belong to the boundary. But, as $A$ is closed, it contains its own boundary.

On the other hand, if the boundary is empty, each of its points is a cluster point, vacuously.

We now don't even need that $A$ is closed.

Let $x$ be in the boundary of $A$ and suppose it's not a cluster point. Then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap A=\{x\}$ (the intersection cannot be empty, since $x$ is in the boundary). Hence $x$ is an isolated point in the relative topology of $A$.

We have proved that: if $A$ is a set with no isolated point, then every point in its boundary is a cluster point; in symbols $\operatorname{Bd}A\subseteq A'$.